# Can I use a larger battery in my Galaxy S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s, battery

I have standard 1500mah battery in my Samsung Galaxy S phone and it lasts around 24 hours. Can I use a larger (say 1650mAh) battery so I can get a bit more battery life?

Comment: What battery is this, exactly? Is it an official Samsung battery for the SGS?

Comment: Which battery you want to know, are you asking about 1650Mah battery?

Comment: Yeah, the current battery's irrelevant.

Answer (score 4):

A battery such as [this extended battery](http://www.mugen-power-batteries.com/samsung/samsung-galaxy-s-i9000/mugen-power-1600mah-extended-battery-for-samsung-galaxys-i9000.html) from Mugen Power can be used on the Galaxy S without adding thickness and will usually give you around 30% better battery life. Always be careful when using non-OEM batteries in your phone, there are a lot of cheap ones out there, but a no-name brand battery might leak or short out. Read the reviews and remember, you get what you pay for.